# solve problem of not plus shipping method price in total in multiple shipping overview page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

[image]

any one have solution about the below image please help me

Comment: Did you create a new shipping method? If so then can I have the code for that? From the picture I infer that the shipping rates is not getting calculated correctly. There must be some issues in the code that is used to create the shipping method